# VS code run: Cannot open database - but SSMS can and is connected

Tags: sql, visual-studio, iis, ssms

I will post this one last time as I believe this is a **very complex issue**.

I'm running code created in VS 2015. This is a website which has been working online for years and I recently purchased.

I received all source and build code, yet I can never run the VS code without  browser error :

'Cannot open database'
Login failed for user 'sa'

Trust me, **this is a false error** as I do have the db attached and running in SSMS. I do have correct permissions set for user sa. I do have the correct connections string in my web.config file.

There must be conflicting software or software versions installed on my computer. Something other than what the error states is the true culprit.

If anyone has had a similar issue, let's discuss please.

Comment: Can you share the connection string?

Comment: Do you have the correct password for sa?  Is the login sa associated with a database user that can access the database?

Comment: Yes, using 'sa' it's not a connection string error or permissions error. Thinking it could be just how my computer is set up since it's Win7 Home Premium and may not have all the functionality I need.